# What is the difference between UnauthorizedException vs OAuthRequestException in Cloud Endpoints?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

In Cloud Endpoints, I understand that when doing OAuth I need to check if `user == null` to determine if a user has authenticated. In the case that the user is null I should throw an exception. In sample Google Cloud Endpoints code snippets I have seen two different exceptions being used though.

The [OAuth documentation for cloud endpoints](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/auth) says to throw `OAuthRequestException`. However, I have seen other code bases (including a [Udacity Course](https://github.com/udacity/ud859/blob/master/Lesson_6/00_Conference_Central/src/main/java/com/google/devrel/training/conference/spi/ConferenceApi.java)) throw `UnauthorizedException`.

I've noticed that OAuthRequestException does not extends from com.google.api.server.spi.ServiceException so Im thinking UnauthorizedException is the correct choice?

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would stick to `UnauthorizedException' since it extends from the`ServiceException` class. As per the documentation at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/exceptions and from API Best Practices, it is advisable to map the exceptions in a manner such that the correct HTTP Status Code is thrown.

So, in the case of the `UnauthorizedException` , HTTP 401 is thrown.

This is what I usually do in my code and I believe (and which you can try!) that you will see a standard catch all HTTP Error Code being thrown back in case you throw exceptions like `OAuthRequestException` that do not extend `ServiceException` (HTTP 503 or HTTP 500)